# Living Things From Non-Living atoms and molecules

Tags: science, philosophy

> **The most amazing thing about a living system is that it is made up of non-living atoms and molecules!!!**

This beautiful thought just got me awestruck, the abstract feelings that we have are just some exchange of non-living compounds that indeed control us...

Even myself thinking or writing this text is due to these non-living stuff.

so the saintly concept of desires are a null set is actually a scientific concept, we let these non-living compounds control ourselves, and maybe one day we know how to control them.

*What are your thoughts on this?*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with writing or the scope of Writing.SE

Comment: @user2352714 Big oof

Comment: @Acid Kritana Big oof?? What this means?

Comment: @AbhinandanAngra It means that your question got closed and I find it to be a big oof (Big oof is basically an exclaimed form of oof that sucks if you're still confused)

Comment: Well, it wasn't closed yet, but they are voting for it to be closed.

Comment: @AcidKritana got it. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I would not say that atoms and molecules are non-living. They move and interact, and often without any external influence.

Comment: @AbhinandanAngra You didn't waste my time. I was the one who chose to comment back. In fact, I love talking with people! So it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I completely agree. Very interesting thought process of it, though!

I'll keep it in mind when writing stories or just doing scientific stuff.

Think of more awesome stuff!

Comment: Please don't answer such blatantly off-topic questions.

Comment: @F1Krazy Ok. It's fine, I'll keep that in mind next time.